# getting herarical data from Parent-child tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

There are 3 data tables:

**productCategory**
It has data of basic categories. This table has two columns( categoryid, categorydescription).

```
Sample Data
101 MENS
102 WOMENS
103 CHILDRENS
104 BABIES
105 FOOTWEAR
106 HANDBAGS
107 JEANS
108 ACCESSORIES
```

**productType**
This table has data of subcategories. It also has two columns (categoryId, producttypedescription).

```
Sample Data
112 OTHER
113 JUMPERS
114 WOMENS SHOES
115 JEANS
116 MENS
117 WOMENS
118 KIDS
119 ACCESORIES
```

**categoryLink**
This table manage there many to many relationship, it has two columns(category, productTypeId).

```
sample Data
101 112
101 113
102 112
102 113
102 114
103 112
103 113
104 112
104 113
104 119
105 112
105 113
105 114
106 112
107 116
107 117
107 118
```

I need to have this data in hierarchical model to display in menus. I am not getting query to do that.

Required Result Set **(I just have produced this just for one code but need all such result combination)**

```
'Category','Category_description','ParentCategory'
'101','MENS','null',
'112','OTHER','101',
'113','JUMPERS','101';
```

Kindly guide and help me.

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? I'm guessing SQL relational type, but which one specifically (PostgreSQL/MySQL/Oracle/MS SQL)?

Comment: Can you please show some sample data and desired results.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at posts on StackOverflow with the `hierarchy` tag?

Comment: @Algomorph, I am using SQL Server and sample data is provided.

Comment: @Aaron Mertrand, Thanks. I have provided sample data and result set.

Comment: What is the hierarchy you want in the menus?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the logic. Why in your sample result set do you have data from both productType's producttypedescription column *and* productCategory's categorydescription column mixed?

If the productCategory and productType all have unique categoryIds, why not just put all of those into one table? They don't represent a hierarchy, at least not how you set the result right now, since if productCategory is supposed to be the super-category and productType - the sub-category, your first entry in the result defies this. If it's vice-versa, then the other two defy this.

Comment: If you actually do combine them into one table, then you can do this (i.e. no clear "parent" or "child", just read from one table based on the given key, then read from the same table again based on the second key) and then we can help you.

Comment: It is not just the values that are off.  What is CategoryID in ProductDesction?   Then category, productTypeId in the categorylink.  Clean up you tables and your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server 2008 has some hierarchy features built into it that you may want to check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manisblog/archive/2007/08/17/sql-server-2008-hierarchyid.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx

Comment: Kudos Mr. Moore, for an extremely vague question - an extremely vague answer is in order. I believe this is more of a question about database schema design, and the links you've posted clearly should help organize the tables much better.